# Count the occurence of a particular number in a file in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

My file has 10 lines:

```
line one word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.444 dst=123.456.5.35
line two word=bnd1 src=123.456.5.78 dst=123.456.5.35
line three word=bnd1 src=123.456.5.78 dst=123.456.5.35
line four word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.444 dst=123.456.5.35
line five word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.234 dst=123.456.5.35
line six word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.234 dst=123.456.5.35
line seven word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.234 dst=123.456.5.35
line eight word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.775 dst=123.456.5.35
line nine word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.775 dst=123.456.5.35
line ten word=bnd1 src=123.456.5.78 dst=123.456.5.3
```

I need to count the occurence of the src ip address where word=bnd0.
I should only consider the lines with value bnd0 other lines can be excluded.

My output should look like

```
123.456.5.444 - 2
123.456.5.234  - 3
123.456.5.775 - 2
```

I am new to shell script. I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) There are already many answers along these lines on this site.

Comment: I have searched, but i am not getting any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

This is your file:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cat ff.txt
line one word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.444 dst=123.456.5.35
line two word=bnd1 src=123.456.5.78 dst=123.456.5.35
line three word=bnd1 src=123.456.5.78 dst=123.456.5.35
line four word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.444 dst=123.456.5.35
line five word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.234 dst=123.456.5.35
line six word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.234 dst=123.456.5.35
line seven word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.234 dst=123.456.5.35
line eight word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.775 dst=123.456.5.35
line nine word=bnd0 src=123.456.5.775 dst=123.456.5.35
line ten word=bnd1 src=123.456.5.78 dst=123.456.5.3
```

Output:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ grep 'word=bnd0' ff.txt | awk -F'src=' '{print $2}' | awk -F'dst=' '{print $1}' |uniq -c
      2 123.456.5.444 
      3 123.456.5.234 
      2 123.456.5.775
```

You can play around with the above output to print it in your desired format.

**Explanation**:

`grep 'word=bnd0' ff.txt` : This will search for the lines having `word=bnd0`, rest of the line will be excluded.

`awk -F'src=' '{print $2}'` : This awk command will split the above lines based on `src=` as delimiter and will pick the content that occurs after `src=`.

`awk -F'dst=' '{print $1}'` : This awk command will split on delimiter `dst=` and will pick the content before `dst=`.

So, now we are left with only the actual ip_addr for the selected lines.

`uniq -c` : Will find only the unique lines from the above output and would print the count of the duplicates.

Comment: I couldn't even guess how this piece of code works. Is there any good materials to understand the awk concept in shell script @mayank

Comment: @Manoj I've explained the command I used in my answer. You can google more on `awk` to learn.

Comment: How can we print the output in a desired format as output is only retrievable only at the end.

Comment: With the above solution i face a problem.5 197.249.5.116, 1 83.48.119.243, 4 197.249.5.116. Here the 1st and the 3rd value are the same, but while displaying it is been displayed seperately. My output should be 9 197.249.5.116, 1 83.48.119.243. Is there any solution for this @mayank

Comment: Hi... Sorting the records will do so...Thank you @mayank